# MS Excel - fill in missing numbers in column

Tags: microsoft-excel

So my table looks like this

```
20     1
25     1
28     1
```

Is there a way to have Excel create rows that contain the missing numbers?

The end result would look like this.

```
20     1
21     0
22     0
23     0
24     0
25     1
26     0
27     0
28     1
```

Comment: Elaborate please as to why you can't just do this manually? There are many ways to tackle your question. We need more details.

Comment: That was just an example, my actual table has a lot more rows so doing it manually isn't feasible. The value in the second column doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

First put `20,21,22,23...` in a column you need to enter `20` in `A1`, in cell `E1` enter `1` and then enter `=A1+$E$1` in `A2`. After you did that pull the cell `A2` down. that will make you 22,23...

Put you values in row G: in `G1` `20`, `G2` `25` and `G3` `28`.
In cell `B1` put this formula `=IF(VLOOKUP(A1;G:G;1;1)=A1;1)`. After that pull the cell `B1` down.

In B1 put `=IF(VLOOKUP(A1;G:G;1;1)=A1;1;0)` because if you put `=IF(VLOOKUP(A1;G:G;1;1)=A1;1)` there will be `FALSE` instead of `0`.

Comment: Did my answer worked for you? @Hossw

Comment: Your upload link is triggering malware scanners and has been removed. See https://www.virustotal.com/#/url/8da9088c204b9bcfc639a85648ce1af859b42e25f9643f6332100b305953e39e/detection